# sysui_nav_bar element that does nothing? (create a dead spot on the navigation bar)

Tags: navigation-bar

For accessibility reasons, I want to create a dead spot on the bottom right corner of an Android Pie phone (Xiaomi Mi A3) so that touching it does nothing.

The phone comes with new style 2 button nav and pill shaped home button. I've tried to customize the nav bar with the "settings put secure sysui_nav_bar" trick and I've managed to get the buttons I want but cannot create a dead spot on the right side (or anywhere) because it always treats the left and right side as part of the nearest button, even if you add a "space" element there.  The best I've come up with is

```
adb shell
settings put secure sysui_nav_bar "back;space,home,space,space,space;recent,contextual"
```

This creates a left-justified nav bar, with the contextual button on the right acting as a dead spot EXCEPT when the contextual icon actually appears.

What I need is an element that does nothing, or perhaps one that practically no app uses any more so it effectively does nothing. Is there such a thing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the "contextual" part from your command seems to achieve what you need.
i.e.

```
adb shell
settings put secure sysui_nav_bar "back;space,home,space,space,space;recent"
```